# Program to cause 1 sec delay in C and than print stuff

Tags: c

example 
sec 1 ---
sec 2 ---
sec 3 ---

Each print should have a delay of 1 sec.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: This is going to be homework.

Comment: I cannot think of any function so far or any way

Answer (score 3):

In the absense of *any* other information in your question...

You should find a `sleep` function in nearly any C environment (note that it's all lower case). It's usually in `time.h` or `unistd.h`, and accepts the number of seconds that it should delay execution.

Many environments will also have `nanosleep`, which is an equivalent that accepts a number of nanoseconds rather than seconds. Also in `time.h` on many systems.

Bottom-line is that your C environment is likely to provide such a function, whether it's `sleep`, `_sleep`, `Sleep`, or something else similar, and whether it accepts seconds, nanoseconds, or milliseconds. You'll have to refer to the documentation for your environment to find the specific one.

Comment: Unless you are on windows, then it's uppercase `Sleep(ms)`.

Comment: @RedX: Yes, `Sleep` on Windows (which takes milliseconds rather than seconds), or `_sleep` on some other systems. Again, the absense of the OP providing any useful context, all one an do is point in *generally* the right direction... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <windows.h>

...

Sleep(timeInMilliseconds); //sleeps the current thread
```

hth

Comment: Where did the questioner say "Windows"?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Nowhere. My answer is a solution for windows

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a portable version of `sleep()` so instead you could write a `delay()` function using the standard functions in `time.h` as follows:

```
void delay(int seconds)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    while (difftime(time(NULL), t) < seconds) ;
}
```

Note that this isn't ideal as it keeps the cpu busy during the delay.

Comment: This is not sleeping - it's pegging the CPU until some amount of time has surpassed.

Comment: @Kent: Being fair to Lawrence, the OP didn't say he wanted the process to *sleep*. Just delay. A busy-wait will delay things alright. ;-) Not a good solution, of course, but...

Comment: @Kent and @T.J. I agree with both of you.  I have altered the function name to make it clear that it is a delay as per OP. This looks like it is only homework, so it answers the question in a portable way and I agree it isn't ideal.

Comment: @littleadv It may not be homework, and how to implement a delay is a legitimate question.  The other answers are fine solutions, but without knowing the platform they may not answer the question.  Therefore I have shown how to do this in a portable way.